# Best mythical creature to use as livestock?

Tags: fantasy-races, mythical-creatures, domestication, low-fantasy, livestock

Imagine a world where all the magical and fantastical creatures that exist in mythology or folklore actually exist. Everything from dragons, griffins, goblins, harpies, trolls, etc. - they can taken from any history or culture, and assume that the ecosystem has evolved to accept them all.

In that world, which fantastical creature would be the most likely candidate to be domesticated and used by humans as livestock? What would be a fantasy world's equivalent of cows and sheep?

Mythical creatures rooted in folklore are preferred, but modern fantasy variations are also acceptable. Bonus for any lesser known mythical creatures suggested.

Comment: "What is the best X?" questions are frequently closed if you do not avoid being [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437), which you haven't.  Every fantasy creature has be described, used, redefined, reused, over and over.  (a) You must specifically define the physiological characteristics of the creatures you want us to evaluate.  (b) You must define the specific aspects of "livestock" in consideration (food source?  transport? etc.).  (c) You must explain how you will judge the (or what makes a) best answer.

Comment: Would you accept the Shmoo (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmoo) as a mythical creature?

Comment: @JBH When it comes to animal domestication, there are very specific attributes that make a species viable or not, so I would argue that there is a best answer to this question which could be given by someone who specialises in that field.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII, who specializes in the domestication of mythical creatures?  A mythical creature would have those attributes by definition of the author.

Comment: @JBH The mythicality (is that a word?) does complicate matters somewhat, but one could assume that such creatures would have to possess those specific characteristics regardless in order to be domesticated. The OP does suggest they are interested in folkloric creatures, not ones that he/she might make up themselves.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII, you have a point. (\*sigh\*) I wish the OP was online.  Without his/her clarifications, we're guessing as to intent.  After all, who but the OP can assume any such trait belongs to a dragon, a pixie, or a leprechaun?  All these creatures have been defined by so many authors in so many ways that we're forced to make assumptions.  Blech.

Comment: **Snuffleupagus** - he always seemed pretty chill.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley The Shmoo would get my vote. A wise choice. :)

Comment: * *mythical creature* : must be part of an IP worth over a billion dollars? (too broad...) or ideally, whatever is high enough to disclude Pokemon...

Comment: Genies, Gins and Trolls were on my mind for this but I settled to write a more traditional answer.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII I wouldn't say I "specialise" in mythical creatures but I dabble. And from my perspective, this question is unanswerable. Each creature can have so many representations, that each should be considered separate. At the same time some are actually the same creature with different descriptions. So, you can pick and choose traits you want. At this point you are essentially making up a new creature and slapping a mythological name on it.

Answer (score 10):

## Perfectly Normal Beast

Source: Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy (mostly harmless).

Location: Lamuella, Anhondo Plain

Food benefit: Arthur Dent makes their meat into a rather nice sandwich, and for it he become's "Sandwich Maker" to the people of Lamuella. Some actually call him "Bob's only Begotten Sandwich Maker" which should be a testament to the quality of the sandwich which is made from the meat of the Perfectly Normal Beast. Arthur claims that it is a bit like a cow.

Mysterious property: They migrate in an unexplained way twice a year on the planet of Lamuella before disappearing completely into oblivion.

Old Thrashbarg calls them "Perfectly Normal" Saying that "they come from where they come from, and they go to where they go to, and it's all Bob's will, so it's all perfectly normal".

"Who's "Bob"?"... "Don't ask."

Spoiler: They go to the Domain of "The King", which is apparently their true home.

Comment: Why would they make a good candidate for domestication, though? They seem like they're basically cows, but all but impossible to domesticate.

Comment: How do you domesticate something that teleports off on you?

Comment: I'm not sure it qualifies as mythical.

Comment: _**"Who's "Bob"?**_ _In the beginning there was Bob & Bob said_ "let there be light".. "I said let there be light".. "Argh!" [Bob bangs his shin into the coffee table].. CLICK [Bob finds the light switch] _& there was light._

Comment: ^ Actually given where the perfectly normal beasts go to & as it happens also where they come from (the domain of The King), I could be persuaded the Bob in question was (meant by the author to have the last name of) Marley?

Comment: @Pelinore [The king is Elvis Presley](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/The_Domain_of_The_King) actually.

Comment: @Tr1et : Yes I know, & knew, that fact (that I knew) was integral to my point, that the fact that he was on a musical theme with the The King (aka Elvis) could allow me to be persuaded that the Bob Thrashbarg keeps going on about could have been (in Douglas Adams whimsical mind) Bob Marley.

Comment: @Thorne It doesn't seem like the beasts have an inherent teleportation ability, it's more that their migratory pattern just happens to pass through some sort of teleportation portal or inter dimensional wormhole. Because the heroes of the story get off Lamuella by hitching a ride on them.

Answer (score 8):

**The perfect creature**

The [Sæhrímnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A6hr%C3%ADmnir) is from Norse mythology

> "In Norse mythology, Sæhrímnir is the creature killed and eaten every
>   night by the Æsir and einherjar. The cook of the gods, Andhrímnir, is
>   responsible for the slaughter of Sæhrímnir and its preparation in the
>   cauldron Eldhrímnir. After Sæhrímnir is eaten, the beast is brought
>   back to life again to provide sustenance for the following day."

Basically it's a pig that comes back to life

Comment: +1 for infinite bacon

Comment: It's not a very good farm animal for Muslims.

Comment: Odin cares not for their problems......

Comment: There's only one small problem with this answer, it's a unique creature not a species, there's only one, it doesn't reproduce, it belongs to Odin & he's not selling.

Comment: Didn't Thor have two regenerating goats as well?

Comment: Came here to say any number of the regenerating food animals you find scattered around almost every religious complex. Sæhrímnir is the most widely known in the West.

Comment: Thor used his hammer to bring his goats back to life

Answer (score 7):

Though it is extremely dangerous, if a Hydra were domesticated (or held in captivity successfully), it does provide enough meat to feed virtually any size population. If you cut off one head, two more grow back immediately, so the Hydra only increases in total head count. Presumably, there is some amount of Hydra neck which also comes with each head, from which several good sized Hydra steaks can be cut. I'd imagine the meat would be a bit like crocodile; probably about halfway between chicken and fish. Obviously, Hydra farming is not for the faint of heart, but considering how much high quality meat could be harvested from a single Hydra in a very short time, it would certainly be worth it.

Griffons and Hippogriffs are obvious candidates for domesticated riding beasts. The ability to fly with a passenger is a pretty good reason to use them.

Medieval Europe and Japan both had lots of stories about domestic fey which would hide around a peasant hut and (in return for small amounts of food left out for it) would do work that benefited the peasants, like repairing furniture or buildings or reaping a field in the night. Certainly no mythology-derived economy would be complete without worker fey.

Dragons are always interesting, not so much as something that is likely to be domesticated, but potentially as something which might be partnered with. Most myths have dragons being as intelligent as humans, and certainly in Western myths, they could often belt out fire hotter than that produced by any forge. The natural outcome of that might be a dragon-powered blast furnace that can produce alloys unavailable anywhere else. Obviously, the dragon would have to benefit from this arrangement, so there would have to be a quid-pro-quo of something they want in return for a few hours blowing into a big stone tower.

Will-o-wisps or pixies kept in jars may be useful sources of light in a pre-electrical setting. Maybe they can be fed with honey, or something equally cheap (though the tales of will-o-wisps usually imply that they "feed" on the dead souls of poor fools who follow their lights into a bog and die).

There are many, many more possibilities...

Comment: Possible useful reference: [Order of the Stick: Getting Ahead In Business](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0326.html)

Comment: @EdGrimm - You just beat me!

Comment: Apparently in ancient myth, the Hydra was poisonous anyway, so... meh. It was an interesting idea.

Answer (score 4):

**The [Hydra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernaean_Hydra)**

It would probably be a real bitch to tame. But the reward for doing so is awesome: an essentially infinite supply of hydra heads that grow back near instantly.

(There's probably other mythical creatures with similarly fantastical regeneration/multiplicative abilities, perhaps ones that are less dangerous, but the hydra's the first that came to mind.)

Comment: Trolls are the obvious other choice, I doubt they taste good though. This was my obvious first thought too though :)

Comment: Wasn't the hydra's blood poisonous?

Comment: The Lernaean Hydra or Hydra of Lerna more often known simply as the Hydra, is a serpentine .... Heracles would later use arrows dipped in the Hydra's poisonous blood to kill other foes during his remaining labors, such as Stymphalian Birds

Comment: @Thorne yeah - SUPER poisonous. Heracles' arrows were one-hit kill on anything. For years after the hydra was slain.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, a serious economical evaluation—what is the most profitable creature to use as livestock?—should consider feeding and well-being costs specific to the species, which may vary wildly for the same creature in different traditions (something like creature X in tradition Y only mates once per millenium, but in tradition Z it mates on every blue Moon)

**Option 1:** [**The Goose That Laid the Golden Eggs**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goose_That_Laid_the_Golden_Eggs) assuming you can clone it or get it to reproduce it in some other way and it qualifies as a mythical creature (which arguably does).

- **Update:** a number of sources go back to [this paper](https://www.agriculturejournals.cz/publicFiles/131329.pdf) to say that a goose's egg is about $150\,cm^3$ or around $2900\,g$ of gold (given gold density of $19.32\,g/cm^3$. That means about $93\,$troy ounces (assuming the golden eggs are the same size as regular goose eggs). At current gold market price it means USD\$$\,$110,000 per egg. The number of eggs a goose lays per year [goes from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_goose) 5 (for mediocre wild geese) to 50 (for the best domestic geese). So you could get anything from $15$ to $150\,kg$ of gold per goose per year worth $0.5$ to $5$ million USD respectively.

  The world's annual gold production is approaching $3000\,tons$ (3 million kg). So even a farm with hundreds of geese wouldn't affect the world gold market too heavily. (In the *worst* case 100 laying geese hens would make $150\,kg\times100\,geese=15000\,kg=15\,tons$ of gold per year.)

  > **Conclusion:** one farm of golden-egg-laying geese would be **enough to make you rich, but not enough to disrupt the world gold market**.

  Now, if these geese are super abundant/easy to reproduce, that's a different story.

**Option 2:** **Unicorns**. They can provide both transportation and food. Their [horns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn_horn) purify water and have several medical properties, including serving as antipoison. Their [tails and blood](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8889/what-are-the-uses-of-unicorns) also have magical properties.

Comment: Canned Unicorn meat https://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e5a7/

Comment: Gold isn't that valuable if it isn't that rare. That having been said, combine your herd of unicorns with their poison-dispelling horns and a hydra...

Comment: The golden eggs goose would be profitable for a short while. If you have a whole farm of them, shorter still. Once the price of gold plummets from over-supply, they'd be pretty worthless. Or worse - they would be better off dead.

Comment: If the unicorns can only be handled by virgins, then the difficulty of keeping them goes way up.  On the other hand, if they tolerate everyone but get really docile with virgins, the difficulty goes way down.

Comment: @EdGrimm thanks for the observation, I hadn't really thought about that. I did the numbers. I could be proven wrong, but it seems to me that a farm of golden-laying-geese wouldn't be that disruptive, though. I'd be grateful to hear your thoughts about that!

Comment: @VLAZ the previous comment is also for you. Unfortunately SE doesn't allow to tag two people at a time.

Comment: @Thorne: I just learned about unicorn meat while I was doing my research for this answer, but I was hesitant to include it. It's a fun fact anyway!

Comment: @Rafael a farm of golden egg laying geese might not be disruptive *today* but it depends what sort of setting and/or time period this world is in. In 14th century Mansa Musa was the richest guy around with a lot of gold and salt mines. Also a devout Muslim. So he went on a hajj (a Muslim pilgrimage) to Mecca and while there just gave away gold as charity. That managed to plummet the price of gold in the area for *the next 10 years*. After giving so much gold, he *costed* money to the area.

Comment: Your major miscalculation with the geese is you're assuming that you're the only one with the geese, and you're the only one making extra gold. In this setting, neither of those is a safe assumption. The price of gold is going to plummet, regardless of what any one person does.

Comment: @EdGrimm, unless their reproduction is a well kept secret. That's up to the OP to decide. That's why I said _one_ farm wouldn't be disruptive, and added "_Now, if these geese are super abundant/easy to reproduce, that's a different story._" at the end.

Comment: @EdGrimm under the premise that anyone will be able to farm whatever mythical creature you can farm, **any** market will eventually reach an equilibrium where it is not super profitable but enough for a living.

Answer (score 4):

### [The Vegetable Lamb of Tartary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetable_Lamb_of_Tartary)

An odd Northern European tale says there's a plant that grows in asia with sheep as its fruit. The sheep are very much alive, so it's not all plant - they walk around and graze the grass, attached to the plant by an umbilical cord. The plant and sheep die when the grass runs out, but I suppose you could keep feeding them more grass and get by.

The advantages? You don't have to support livestock except to feed them, which are usually harder to raise than plants and jack up your prices. You don't have to tame them, or watch them carefully so they don't wander away, worry about legendary enclosures for legendary creatures, etc. You just plant, tend, make sure the Big Bad Wolf stays on the appropriate side of your fence, and prune in season!

You'll even get the wool as a bonus. Livestock are good for more than just meat you know!

(In fairness about obscurity: it was at the top of a Wikipedia page. But who doesn't wish mutton grew on trees?)

Answer (score 4):

## Humans

(And other humanoids such as elves, orcs etc.)

Outrageous, you say? Wait until I'm done.

It may seem a little evil and inhuman to raise intelligent, sentient beings for food and leather. That's clearly not enough, so use the [polymorph spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/polymorph.htm) to make it proper and a lot evil by turning them into actual livestock! And then you can turn them into whatever beast suits your economic needs at the moment.

Advantage over other alternatives: besides having the right cattle for the right time, you solve problems related to POW's, overpopulation, crowded prisons and dissidency, all in one go.

Comment: Well, we found the evil emperor...

Comment: Oh, one problem though... When the creature drops to zero hit points the polymorph spell ends and the creature returns to its original form... so you wouldn't be able to slaughter them for resources...

Comment: @ArkensteinXII Slaughtering them? You monster! Don't kill them for meat, take some chunks here and there and use healing to keep your cash cow alive

Comment: The spell only affects the contiguous creature, so the bits you chop off revert, too.

Comment: It's economically unwise to slaughter any of your customer base to sell to your other customers, you can halve your potential customers each week this way (if you're selling sausages say) until you've none left, then who will you sell stuff to?

Answer (score 1):

## Dragons

Of the several varieties of dragons, farming can be greatly adantaged by replacing traditional oxen, cattle or ass with farm dragons to pull the harvest and sowing machines. Agriculture can most definitely be benefited by flying serpants and pest control is an assured, hence minimal crop damage.

Clearing corn feilds would also be a sinch given a few fire breathers and most dragons are friendly like cattle but can be ridden like horses. There are several more obvious advantages that I'll best leave to your imagination.

Answer (score -1):

A [Cockatrice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockatrice) might pass for a decent farm animal. It is part chicken, which means it probably tasted good. They also lay sizable eggs, which can serve as an additional source of protein.

Comment: Where do you find that Cockatrice's lay eggs?  According to the Wiki page you link to, a cockatrice is the product of a cock's egg (an egg laid by a male chicken) incubated in a toad or a snake.  Can you cite an authority that suggests the mythology of the Cockatrice included laying eggs?

Comment: Here is a source that says cockatrice lay eggs. Cockatrice have to reproduce some way and only mammals give birth to live young generally. It stands to reason that since both dragons and chickens lay eggs that a cockatrice would to. http://www.biblestudy.org/bible-study-by-topic/mythical-animals-in-the-bible/cockatrice.html

Comment: The biblical cockatrice was most likely a snake - even that bible study link says that.  Most snakes do lay eggs (even the Adder, which many think the biblical cockatrice refers to, although they're ovoviviparous).  The biblical cockatrice is not the cockatrice of fantasy described by your Wiki link or, without clarification, what the OP intended.

Comment: @SciFiGuy They probably do lay eggs, but I'm not familiar with any bird-cockatrices in the bible, and the link also references the asp incorrectly (I believe that is a type of snake?)

Comment: I think they're better as eatchdogs than as livedtock, just like geese.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like a creature that is known for turning things to stone with its gaze, its breath, or its touch is a good choice for live stock, unless your villagers happen to be a bunch of Discworld trolls.

Comment: @EdGrimm and in some legends it dies when it hears "a rooster crow". So, you better not have any chickens around your farm. Also, it's unclear if it has to be a live rooster physically present - somebody plays a sound clip of a rooster, and your entire population of cockatrices dies.